# How to catch "RemotingException"?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, .net-remoting

I'm using native pinvoke calls in my app and external assemblies in dlls.
Everything is working fine, until part of the program stops working and I get:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

multiple times in the Debug Output Window. The execution continues, it just prints that in the output window when I try to execute my code. How to get where the exception occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind the difference between first-chance and second-chance exceptions.  A first-chance exception is throw but may be being caught and handled before you even see it.  This is normal and not too much of a cause for concern.

A second-chance exception is when the exception is throw, and no one catches it, so the exception becomes unhandled and may cause your program to terminate.

Are you concerned just on the debug text, or is it not working?  If it works I wouldn't worry.  If it's a big concern catch it in WinDebug and analyze it, or you can tell the visual studio IDE to stop on first-chance exceptions.

Comment: It's not working. My app is not crashing, but not working properly.

Comment: You'd have to tell the debugger to break on RemotingException.  Go to Debug->Exceptions, and expand "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", then expand System.Runtime.Remoting and select the checkbox for Thrown on RemotingException.  Then run your code under debug and you should break as soon as RemotingException is thrown.  Of course if the problem is not in your code directly but is a symptom of how your code uses the framework that causes the framework to throw it may be harder to diagnose.