# mscorlib.dll throws System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I have a .net application running in local machine connecting to Oracle db hosted in different server .

The version of the Oracle client is 19c .

When the application is ran and during the connection to Oracle db using Oracle.Dataaccess.dll I get the following 2 errors and the request is timing out after waiting for a long time.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' in System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x5737 has exited with code 0 (0*).
....
....
....
```

Is this something related to connectivity to Oracle db from local machine ?
Any steps need to be taken like whitelisting ip etc? any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using the dubugger to see if it will give you any more details? (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309632/how-to-catch-remotingexception). Look specifically at James' instructions in the comments.